# MVC Edit object doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm using Entity Framework, and I have 2 classes:

```
    public class User
    {
            public int UserID { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
            public int PermissionGroupID { get; set; }
            public string Comments { get; set; }

            public virtual PermissionGroup PermissionGroup { get; set; }
    }

public class PermissionGroup
{
        public int PermissionID { get; set; }
        public string PermissionValue { get; set; }
}
```

of course, in my db I have FK between User.PermissionGroupID and PermissionGroup.PermissionID

Now, I'm trying to do the edit controller and view using a UserModel:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public SelectList PermissionGroups { get; set; }
    public int SelectedPermissionGroup { get; set; }
}
```

with the controller:

```
   public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        UserModel model = new UserModel ();
        model.User= managerUser.GetObjectById(id);
        model.PermissionGroups = new SelectList(managerPermission.GetAllList(), "PermissionID ", "PermissionValue");

        if (model.User== null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        model.SelectedPermissionGroup = model.User.PermissionGroupID;

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(UserModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.User.PermissionGroupID = model.SelectedPermissionGroup;
            managerUser.EditObject(model.User);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        UserModel newModel = model;
        newModel.User = managerUser.GetObjectById(model.UserID);
        newModel.PermissionGroups = new SelectList(managerPermission.GetAllList(), "PermissionID ", "PermissionValue");

        return View(newModel);
    }
```

The EditObject in the manager is this:

```
public virtual int EditObject(T objToEdit)
{
    DbEntities.Set<T>().Attach(objToEdit);
    DbEntities.Entry(objToEdit).State = EntityState.Modified;
    return DbEntities.SaveChanges();
}
```

And in my view I'll not put evrything, this is what I have:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>User</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.User.UserID)

//Everything else to edit about the user....

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.PermissionGroupID)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedPermissionGroup, Model.PermissionGroups, new { @class = "form-control" })
            <p class="help-block">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.PermissionGroupID)</p>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            @Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index")
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

So, When I click "Save", according to my breakpoints, it passes everything correctly but the PermissionGroup property in User class is not populated as the PermissionGroupID (it does recieve the ID from the selected dropdown.
And then it returns to the Index view but without any of the changes I made.

**I used the exact same EditObject method in other projects and it worked fine, with dropdownlist and all.**

What am I missing?

Comment: is the value of `model.SelectedPermissionGroup` the correctly value in your post method

Comment: hoping I undertood your quiestion, yes, in the view it shows the correct permission gorup of the user I chose to edit. And when I put a breakpoint after the saving, the model.SelectedPermissionGroup is given the correct permission I changed to.

Comment: Ok then I miss understand you're question, I take it saving works, it's when the `View(newModel);` is returned it doesn't have the changes you made

Comment: It never gets to the newModel because 'ModelState.IsValid' is true, so it breaks in 'return RedirectToAction("Index");' but the changes I made were not save.

Comment: Was SaveChanges called somewhere, perhaps inside `managerUser.EditObject(model.User);`?

Comment: What does `managerUser.EditObject` do? Can we see that code?

Comment: fine, I edited the post with the EditObject method. Don't forget what I wrote- this exact same methods in other prject are work fine!

Comment: Try to show the full ValidationSummary: `@Html.ValidationSummary(false)` and it will show the property not validating...

Comment: I don't understan what you refering to, but with @Html.ValidationSummary(false) I still get the problem.

Comment: It's not supposed to fix the problem but only to show the full validation error...

Answer (score 0):

i suspect that here is the mistake, you are validating for `Model.User.PermissionGroupID` but you have binded dropdown list with `Model.SelectedPermissionGroup`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedPermissionGroup, 
                      Model.PermissionGroups, 
                      new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.PermissionGroupID)
```

it should be this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.User.PermissionGroupID, 
                               Model.PermissionGroups, 
                               new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.PermissionGroupID)
```

Comment: can you please tell me which property is posting null??

Comment: the User class have the property from EntityFramework: `public virtual PermissionGroup PermissionGroup { get; set; }` so User.PermissionGroup is null.

Comment: means model.SelectedPermissionGroup is null in edit post action right?

Comment: no, model.SelectedPermissionGroup is getting the chosen id permission group correctly, and it passes the id to the mode.User.PermissionGroupID fine, but the property PermissionGroup is still null and none of the changes are made.

Comment: @user2254436 you never metioned User having a `PermissionGroup` property. Anyway, when you save you only save the `PermissionGroupID`, EF does not automatically load the navigational property when this happens... it will load it (lazily) the next time it loads the user.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it's clear that if I'm using EF and FK between the two ID's it's clear that User has a property to this. Anyway, the next time it sopuse to load the user is in Index view where all Users list is shown, but the changed are not made.

Comment: Is the PermissionGroupID in the database saved correctly? Most importantly, is the FK created by EF or did you create it yourself in the DB? In the latter case, EF will be completely oblivious to it if it's not made aware from code.

Comment: none of the changes I made where saved, even when I'm not changing the permission (just the username, for example)... the FK I created from DB and the EF automatically created the class with the properties.